# if statement around onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

What is the best way to ignore running code when a button is clicked? I am trying the following but I currently get not reaction how I want it done.

```
if (!document.getElementById('btn_Cancel').getAttribute('onclick')) {
      // code not to be ran when button is clicked
         By default code gets ran when a textbox goes onblur so do not want that code ran when button gets clicked
}
```

Comment: "Ignore running code?" "Code not to be ran?" What? What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: you could [remove the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)

Comment: When you click a button, you want *not* to run code? I'm not sure I'm understanding, could you elaborate?

Comment: You usually specify what code you WANT to run in an event handler... if you don't want the code to be executed, just don't put it there!

Comment: If you want code not to run you click on a button, don't add it to the handler.

Comment: By default code gets ran when a text box goes onblur so do not want that code ran when button gets clicked

Comment: @tiff2342: What button?  Why would the code get ran when the button is clicked if it's for a text box's onblur?  Where is this code?  How does it get called?  We're gonna need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to make a reference to that element, so you don't end up looking it up each time it's clicked and you'll need a variable to keep track of whether it's been clicked or not:

```
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('btn_Cancel'),
    clicked = false;

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function() { clicked = !clicked; }, false); 

// assuming this is in a loop or something:
if(!clicked) { 
    // running code 
}
else {
   // clicked, do nothing
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for. However, I can't seem to get any response from within the function where clicked = !clicked; is ;/